# Query SELECT calculated column with condition

Tags: sql, select, firebird

I need to create a column in my SELECT QUERY where it has a condition. Something like this:

```
SELECT NAME, ADDRESS, IF TABLE.COD=101 THEN return TABLE.VALUE AS TABLE  
FROM CRM
```

So the third argument in the SELECT is my calculated column with a condition.

I believe this is simple but I am not being successful on solving this.

Comment: Hint:  `CASE` expressions.

Comment: Please stop SHOUTING the title of your question. It makes the text harder to read, it won't get you help any faster, and it's extremely rude when you come here and SHOUT AT US TO GET ATTENTION. Please stop now.

Comment: https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/fblangref25-en/html/fblangref25-commons-expressions.html#fblangref25-commons-conditional-case

Comment: Sorry Pal, I guess you are wrong. I had no intention of shouting or calling for attention. It is my writing style to use UPPERCASE for SQL commands. Don´t take it personal, ok ?

Comment: what is "TABLE.COD" ? It sounds like a COD column in TABLE table, but you only have single "CRM" tale in your "FROM" clause !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have not provided any data and expected output, It is really difficult to figure out what you exactly want. still you can try below one.

```
SELECT NAME, ADDRESS, (Case WHEN TABLE.COD=101 THEN TABLE.VALUE END) AS TABLE  
FROM CRM
```

Comment: Hi Chetan. It worked ! Sorry I didn´t provide data but I thought my problem was easy to understand without it. Thanks a lot ! Have a good day !

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be using the [`IIF` function](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/chunk/en/refdocs/fblangref40/fblangref40-functions-conditional.html#fblangref40-scalarfuncs-iif).

Frankly, the `IIF` is function only by name, by essence it is a shorthand, a macro substitution expanding into the `CASE` statement.

That close relationship probably was why you mistaken `IF` and `CASE` when writing your statement.

```
 SELECT NAME, ADDRESS, IIF(TABLE.COD=101, TABLE.VALUE, NULL) as TABLE FROM CRM
```

Now, your statement seems not being real. You refer to the `TABLE.COD` and `TABLE.VALUE` - those are clearly some fields from some second table, but you forgot to include it in your `FROM` clause!

Because of that I think what you really may need is not some condition/calculation, but a plain old `OUTER JOIN`.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)

```
 SELECT A.NAME, A,ADDRESS, B.VALUE as TABLE 
 FROM CRM A
   LEFT JOIN SomeTable B ON B.COD=101 AND B.XXXX = A.YYYY
```